# View the type of a C# generic in the debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I hover over a generic type in Visual Studio using the debugger, I don't get the current type, is there a way to display it without going to the immediate window and typing `?typeof(T).Name`?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Then I guessed wrong ;)

Comment: Yeah, I thought typeof was self-explanatory, but I completely forgot CLR C++ :)

Comment: There are `typeid` and `typeof` even in native C++

Comment: typeof is not in the standard

Answer (score 31):

You can see the types in the callstack window by looking at the top line which will show the runtime evaluated type.

Also want to emphasize for others your suggestion:

> going to the immediate window and typing `?typeof(T).Name`

Comment: "You can see the types in the callstack window by looking at the top line which will show the runtime evaluated type" -> IF you enable "show parameter value"

Comment: I would recommend using `?typeof(T).FullName` rather than `.Name`. That is because nested generic types will not show on `.Name`.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a watcher for `typeof(T)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can see full types of variables in watch windows such as "watch", "autos", "locals". Also, you can enable types in call stack window (in right-click context menu).

Here is an example for C++ (works for C# the same way):

[image: Example of a Visual Studio debug session interface with full types]

Comment: Yes, but what if you don't have variables there is nothing to debug, right?

Comment: The type is defining the context and it is also used further down in the stack, so there is something.

Answer (score 0):

1. While debugging, open the `Locals` window.
2. Look for the `Type Variables` section within the `Locals` window.
3. Expand the `Type Variables` section, and you should be able to see
   the runtime types of your generic variables.